# Why does EIEIO's type-predicate fail for subclasses?

Tags: eieio

If I define a class with EIEIO, then define a subclass which inherits from it, I would expect the type predicate for the superclass (automatically defined by EIEIO) to return `t` for instances of the subclass as well, but it doesn't. A simple example:

```lisp
(require 'eieio)

;;; Define the superclass
(defclass super ()
  (a))

;;; Define the subclass
(defclass sub (super)
  nil)

;;; Create an instance of the subclass
(defvar my-instance (sub))

;; `t' as expected
(sub-p my-instance) ;; t

;; I would expect to get `t', but get `nil' instead
(super-p my-instance) ;; nil
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use these instead:

```lisp
(child-of-class-p (eieio-object-class YOUR-SUB-INSTANCE) 'YOUR-SUPER)
;; or
(YOUR-SUPER-child-p YOUR-SUB-INSTANCE)
;; or
(cl-typep YOUR-INSTANCE 'YOUR-SUPER)  ; This function is NOT documented!
```

> Why does EIEIO's type-predicate fail for subclasses?

As far as I know, this is most object systems’ convention.
E.g., `std::DerivedFrom` and `std::Same` are two different *concept*s in C++.

Moreover, the behavior you expect

> ```lisp
> ;; I would expect to get `t', but get `nil' instead
> (super-p my-instance) ;; nil
> ```

is not mentioned in the manual, to say the least.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks so much! This is my first foray into OOP, so I don't know the background.